# Giving training to a person with ADHD

Tags: training, gymnastics, martial-arts, dancing

I am a member of a capoeira group and recently a child of 8 came to us. His mother said that he has a "strong ADHD".

He is visibly different than the other kids. I never encountered someone with ADHD and I don't know what he is feeling.

How do I include a person like this into a group?

Comment: "ADHD" (whether strong or not) is not something which presents in a single way across the population. Talk to the child or his mother as appropriate and **ask** what he needs - that will be far more effective than folks on the Internet guessing.